# Pentaho Kettle Mapping with parameterized Table Input

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I am passing a value to the sub transformation, sub transformation takes the value fine as i have used java-script step to **Alert** it.

But i have a table input step in the sub transformation step, where i need to used the parent transformation value as a parameter to the TABLE INPUT step to run a query against it, but its not working, as the table input step does not understand the field, how can i achieve this behavior?

I am stuck at this point and can't go further.

The only option that is left is to use the **Pentaho JOBS**, but is it possible using **Mapping** inside a transformation?

I tried to **setVariable** function from the **javascript** in the sub transformation but nothing works.

[image: image for the main transformation]

[image: image for the sub transformation]

Comment: Please post some code, or some screenshots of what you have tried.

Comment: I have placed two images in the post just now, please look at them, the sub transformation has an ALERT which catches the parameter correctly, but the Table input does not get it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that your sub transformation is similar to the one in the figure below. Are you sure you are passing the parameters correctly? The important is to:

- have same number of parameters in `Mapping input specification` as parameters used in `Table input` step
- `Replace variables in script` checked
- `Insert data from step` filled
- parameter `?` used in SQL query

[image: Kettle transformation]

If you need to pass **more parameters** to the `table input`, the number of parameters in previous step (`Mapping input specification` in case of my example) needs to **respect the number of parameters** you use in table input. Then you use `?` more times in your query. E.g. for 3 params you could have:

```
WHERE name = ? AND surname = ? AND age = ?
```

Also you need to **respect the order of parameters** which come from previous step:

[image: More params]

Comment: ? did not work, but ${variablenamehere} works,but not data is returned, even the record exists in the database.

Comment: Do you `Mapping (execute sub-transformation)` in your root transformation to run the sub-transformation? Are the `input` and `output` parameters set up correctly in this step? Does it work if you paste sub-transformation's content to root transformation (means you have all in root transformation)? It is easier to make it all work in root transformation and then if some set of steps repeats, move it to sub-transformation.

Comment: I have placed two images in the post just now, please look at them, the sub transformation has an ALERT which catches the parameter correctly, but the Table input does not get it. :(@mzy

Comment: As you can see the image, the query does not get the PARAMERTER, but the sub transformation is receiving the param correctly , the ALERT shows that

Comment: Yes, the bug is in the `SQL query` you use in sub-transformation's table input. Try to replace `'${order_id}'` by `?`. It would be `WHERE a.increment_id = ?`

Comment: no, that's not a bug, we use parameters as ${param} in kettle, but for String params we need to use "${param}", the example image you have in the post is of an older version of pentaho anyways.

Comment: Anyways the error has gone, but i don't receive any output from the sub transformation

Comment: The `${param}` syntax is for inserting **transformation parameters**. It is not for **inserting data from previous step**. Btw an error from your screenshot says it - Error in SQL query. That's because Kettle didn't replace the variable in script.

Comment: then how can it identifies if more than one param is being passed to the sub transformation? anyways i have used ? as well, nothing works. no result comes out of sub transformation

Comment: If you need to pass more parameters to `table input` the number of parameters in `previous step` needs to respect the number of parameters you use in `table input`. Then you use `?` more times in your query. E.g. for 3 params you could have: `WHERE name = ? AND surname = ? AND age = ?`. Also you need to respect the order of parameters which come from `previous step`

Comment: Understood, but right now, there is only one single step, it does not output any result to the parent transformation.

Comment: The easiest way is to `move` sub-transformation steps to root and debug it there to find out it works fine.

Comment: There is no error :( but the sub transformation query does not return anything, if i run that query independently in mysql it returns the rows

Comment: One more thing came to my mind. Are params in `Mapping output specification` and `Mapping (execute sub-transformation)` steps set up correctly?

Comment: Yes they are properly configured, i have matched it with the samples that i have.

Comment: You can log the result of `table input` by `write to log` step. Or when you execute transformation you can set `Log level = Rowlevel (very detailed)` to see more info. I think I have already answered your original question.. Next debugging steps needs to by performed by you. :)

Comment: But i have a table input step in the sub transformation step, where i need to used the parent transformation value as a parameter to the TABLE INPUT step to run a query against it, but its not working, as the table input step does not understand the field, how can i achieve this behavior?

Comment: @shzyincu: When you have been trying with "?" instead of parameter: have you replaced the value in "Insert data from step" with your mapping step? On your screenshot it referes to some non-existing java script.

Comment: Have you tried to log results of table input? What SQL statement is really called (including param values)? What is a data type of the param?

Comment: @user4637357 what do you mean exactly? i have catched the parameter that i have used in the parent transformation input step. javascript was just for the sake of testing, that child transformation is able to receive the VALUE, look at the javascript ALERT, and datatype of the value am sending is STRING

Comment: And what is a data type of `increment_id` db column? Is it varchar? If yes, you might change SQL to `WHERE a.increment_id = '?'`

Comment: Could you post the SQL which works for you when you execute it in database?

Comment: @mzy does it automatically get the sequence for the parameters/values passed when we are using ?

Comment: @user4637357 Alert shows the parameter is being passed successfully to the sub transformation, i have used the ALERT in the sub transformation.

Comment: @mzy it worked, data is retrieved, what should i do with more than one parameters being passed? using ? operator